# Dynamic Spreadsheet

Tags: webmathematica

Fellow Mathfolk,

Please excuse if this question sounds like it’s coming from someone who doesn’t know what they’re talking about.

I own iGrow.net & am trying to imbed a “dynamic spreadsheet,” modeling production capacity of a container farm & its corresponding input resource cost.

**Is it possible to use a Wolfram/Mathematica to embed such a modeling device onto a Sqaurespace &/or Wordpress website? (eg Wolfram Notebook Embedder, webMathematica, etc)**

Apologies if this question is not placed on the right query network. Please feel free to direct me to a better place to ask this question if you know.

With much thanks and gratitude, - SDH